# Linux nginx Permissions

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions

I have an `nginx` box that's not allowing files to be accessed due to `permissions`.  It's a fresh installation with `nginx.conf` set up properly, and the service is indeed running.  Checking the `conf` file shows that it and another file have the wrong `permissions` to test them with the provided tools:

```
$ nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2022/07/28 10:00:20 [emerg] 96525#0: open() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf" failed (13: Permission denied) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How can I change permissions on `/etc` which is owned by `root:root` so I can test them?

Updated: Question: How is it that a fresh installation of `nginx` on a modern `Linux` platform, cannot function due to `permissions` as the way the installation script has terminated properly?  That to me just shows it's introducing a long time to troubleshoot.

Notes: `AlmaLinux 8.6`

Comment: Is your `nginx` running as the nginx user in the nginx group? If so, `chown root:nginx` the files and make them group-readable for the conf and writeable for the log files. Make sure all parent directories are +rx for nginx too

Comment: @BarryCarter Same issue. `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2022/07/28 12:49:34 [emerg] 98895#0: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)` on `root:nginx` with `760` for `log` files.

Comment: double check that nginx will run as the user/group nginx and that this user/group actually exists. `id nginx` should tell you

Comment: @BarryCarter `uid=992(nginx) gid=988(nginx) groups=988(nginx)`

Comment: OK, and you do have +rx perms on /etc and /var for everyone, right? (and /var/log and /etc/nginx and so on). Does /var/log/nginx/error.log already exist. If so, delete it, since it might be owned by root or something weird

Comment: `-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root nginx 524 Jul 28 10:33 error.log`.  I just performed that with `-R` for `/etc` and `/var`.  Deleted all `log` files, same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138080/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-rich-f).